# Is there any tool for flow-diagram available?

Tags: java, workflow, flowchart

is there any tool available, to make a flow diagram or Flow Chart out of code. or make any other diagram like class diagram from the code.

Comment: What platform? What language?

Comment: That's a pretty broad set of requests; "flow charts" answer completely different questions from "class diagrams"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UML plugin in [Netbeans 6.7.1](http://netbeans.org/downloads/6.7.1/index.html) and Reverse Engineer. Unfortunately, the UML plugin is not available in later versions of NetBeans.

Answer (score 4):

1. http://www.websequencediagrams.com/
2. http://yuml.me

Answer (score 3):

Use the yED ( http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html ). It is an excellent free flowchart editor that works on every modern operating system java works on.

I see people recommended UML tools. The only UML diagram that can be used instead of a typical flow-chart is the UML state diagram. Somehow I always found typical flow-charts to be more easy to understand by a person who has no technical background than UML state diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

As you've now said it's Java, here you go:

- **[Java UML generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jug/)**
- <strike>[Enterprise Architect: C# to UML](http://www.sparxsystems.com/)</strike>
- <strike>[Class diagrams in Visual Studio 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsclassdesigner/thread/18284fa2-8938-4490-b8b0-f746606959d1)</strike>

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/)

CASE tools like Rational Rose also do this, but for a price.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider Code Rocket. It can produce flowcharts (and pseudocode) from Java code. You can find more information about it here: http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com

Disclaimer: I am a developer on Code Rocket

Hope this helps.

Alan

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22479409/403571

[code2flow](http://code2flow.com) is an online pseudo-code to flowchart generator which should do what you ask, just click on the image to play with it:

[image: code2flow]